# How to connect postman gRPC mock server by Android app?

Tags: android, https, postman, grpc, grpc-java

I'm struggling to access postman gRPC mock server by Android/kotlin app for several days.

I created the mock server after reading [official document](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/grpc/using-grpc-mock/). I got the URL for mock server and I could get a response by grpcurl and a Node.js gRPC client. However, I got a error when I used the URL by Android gRPC client.
Stacktrace is below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.github.aniokrait.grpcsample/io.github.aniokrait.grpcsample.MainActivity}: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
        at com.book.BookServiceGrpc$BookServiceBlockingStub.getBook(BookServiceGrpc.java:312)
        at io.github.aniokrait.grpcsample.MainActivity$Companion.startGrpc(MainActivity.kt:71)
        at io.github.aniokrait.grpcsample.MainActivity$Companion.access$startGrpc(MainActivity.kt:34)
        at io.github.aniokrait.grpcsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [h2]
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:104)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:218)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:551)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

The messages says "TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [h2]", so I have an idea that the problem is around SSL/TLS, but I don't know how to solve it.
I do not think it is likely to be a certificate issue, as I am able to access the URL from Node.js and grpcurl but the issue of my Android app.

I've read [tls-on-android](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.24.0/SECURITY.md#tls-on-android) and [Update your security provider to protect against SSL exploits](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html).
I added dependecies of play-services and installing code as below but still it doesn't work.

Here's my code.
MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.book.BookServiceGrpc
import com.book.Index.GetBookRequest
import com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller
import io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this@MainActivity)
        startGrpc()
    }

    companion object {
        private fun startGrpc() {
            try {
                val channel = OkHttpChannelBuilder
                    .forAddress("g-95d43o92ollxvwmm7nx895731r4g9y.srv.pstmn.io",443) //URL is slightly altered to prevent tampering
                    .useTransportSecurity()
                    .build()
                val stub = BookServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
                val request = GetBookRequest.newBuilder().setIsbn(123).build()
                val result = stub.getBook(request)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                throw e
            }

        }
    }
}
```

my proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.book;

message Book {
  int64 isbn = 1;
  string title = 2;
  string author = 3;
}

message GetBookRequest {
  int64 isbn = 1;
}

service BookService {
  rpc GetBook (GetBookRequest) returns (Book) {}
}
```

and dependecies relevant to gRPC

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.51.1'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.51.1'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.51.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'
}
```

**Update:**
I found these messages in Debug logs.

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
```

Perhaps The Dynamic Security Provider isn't installed properly, but still I don't know why.

Comment: I wonder if any other OkHttpChannel gets created in some other place before `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded` runs? As there is a note in TLS on Android section: "Note: The Dynamic Security Provider must be installed before creating a gRPC OkHttp channel. gRPC's OkHttpProtocolNegotiator statically initializes the security protocol(s) available to gRPC, which means that changes to the security provider after the first channel is created will not be picked up by gRPC."

Comment: Thank you Yuri, but I don't think OkHttpChannel is created before `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded`.  I've tried stepping through OkHttpChannelBuilder#build() in debug mode just to be sure. The channel looks like created only after build() is called.